# How to exclude file from PHPUnit test suite in xml config?

Tags: unit-testing, configuration, phpunit

I have following, very simple, XML config for PHPUnit:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="/_tests/TestAutoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit Tests">
            <directory suffix=".php">_tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

How to exclude certain file in this directory from test suite? I tried `<exclude>` and `<blacklist>`, but it doesn't seem to work in this context. Also couldn't find any other documentation than [phpunit.de](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/) one, which doesn't mention anything about it. Else than that, this config works perfectly.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid running one or more of your tests?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I'm trying to do. 1 test class = 1 file.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There are a number of ways to not run a particular test - putting it into a blacklist so it's never run may not be the way - as changing it means editing the blacklist, and you'll often endup bouncing it in and out of version control.

**There are several other ways that may be more appropriate:**

*If a test is not yet ready to run:*

```
$this->markTestIncomplete('This test has not been implemented yet.');
```

*If there's an outside reason it should not be run, skip it:*

```
if (!extension_loaded('mysqli')) {
    $this->markTestSkipped('The MySQLi extension is not available.');
}
```

You can also put that into the `setUp()` function, so it will skip all the tests in a test-class.

*You can make a test dependant on a previous one succeeding:*

```
public function testEmpty()
{
    $stack = array();
    $this->assertTrue(empty($stack));
    return $stack;   // also sends this variable to any following tests - if this worked
}
/**
 * only runs if testEmpty() passed
 *
 * @depends testEmpty
 */
public function testPush(array $stack)
{
}
```

*The @group -name- annotation is one of the best ways to specifically stop, or run one group of tests*

```
/**
 * @group database
 * @group remoteTasks
 */
public function testSomething()
{
}
```

`testSomething()` is now in two groups, and if either is added on the command line (or in the config.xml) `--exclude-group` parameter. it won't be run. Likewise, you could run only tests that belong to a particular group - say named after a feature, or bug report.

Comment: I wish @group worked inside the testsuite node in addition to the phpunit node in the config. I had one test that needed to run before a static var was set for all other tests. So I put that one test in a separate test class, with the name RunFirst.php and modified my configuration to run that in a suite all by itself, but before all other suites.

Comment: The syntax for excluding groups in phpunit.xml is as follows
`<groups>`
`<exclude>`
`<group>ExcludedTests</group>`
`</exclude>`
`</groups>`
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49246266/2511355

Answer (score 62):

To exclude the file name `TestCase.php`.

add this to your `phpunit.xml`

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="BLABLA">
        <directory suffix=".php">./tests</directory>
        <exclude>./tests/TestCase.php</exclude>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

---

Here is an additional excerpt from [a real-live test-suite](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun/blob/master/phpunit.xml.dist) I can confirm it working with:

```
...
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="n98-magerun-tests">
            <directory>./tests</directory>
            <exclude>tests/N98/Magento/Command/Installer/UninstallCommandTest.php</exclude>
        </testsuite>
    ...
```

Comment: does this actually work for you? as per previous comment (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15632735/2314626) exclude works for directories.

your proposed configuration still fails with: No tests found in class "TestCase".

Comment: @ElanRuusamäe: Yes it does actually work. That *previous comment* actually is an answer from years ago that even begs to be proven wrong.

Comment: Confirmed. Maybe it didn't used to work, but it certainly does with phpunit 5.3, as well as being the simplest, clearest answer.

Comment: Confirmed that it works for files and directories. I'm using PHPUnit 9.5.7

Comment: In my case it is excluded but also invisible for Autoloader. So tests extending TestCase simply have error can't load the class TestCase

Answer (score 6):

2021 update

On top of some good single answers above here is the entire approach that allows you to apply a consistent, clean, more architecture-driven tests organization and a convinient fast testing workflow. With it you manage your tests, directories and testsuites from `phpunit.xml` and run tests in groups or by one as needed. So do the following:

- Group your tests in the directories (e.g. `tests/Unit`, `tests/Feature`, `tests/Integration`);
- Make testsuites grouping your directories with [`<testsuite>`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/configuration.html#the-testsuites-element) element (note you have to [wrap](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/configuration.html#the-testsuites-element) multiple `<testsuite>` tags in `<testsuites>` tag in later versions of PHPUnit);
- Make an `all` testsuite that combines all default tests you would run as a full test suite and assign it via `defaultTestSuite="all"` key within [`<phpunit>`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/configuration.html#the-phpunit-element) element like this:

```xml
  <phpunit .. some other keys
         defaultTestSuite="all">
    <testsuite name="all">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature/</directory>
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit/</directory>
    </testsuite>   
  </phpunit>
```

- If you need make a dedicated `Tinker` test suite with tests that you could use for tinkering, keeping example tests etc. you would exclude from normal testing workflow. Do not inlcude it in the `all` test suite.

So you will be able to:

- use `phpunit` CLI command to always run the default `all` tests.
- use CLI to filter on testsuite, test file or single test level for any of your test suites e.g.:

  - `phpunit --testsuite SuiteOne`,
  - `phpunit --filter SomeTest` or
  - `phpunit --filter SomeTest::test_some_test_method`
  - combine `--testsuite` with `--filter` arguments

Couple this workflow with the capability to run the current test or test file from within your IDE (for Sublime Text there are [Mac](https://github.com/adamwathan/sublime-phpunit) and [Linux/Windows](https://github.com/adamwathan/sublime-phpunit) plugins) and you will be completelly equipped to instantly chose what test to execute.

Comment: Thank you for `phpunit --filter SomeTest::test_some_test_method`! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Can also be useful to add to this great info that `<exclude>` can take a directory instead of just a file.  In some cases, e.g. you're using a framework that includes tests for features you're not using (yet) it's helpful to just move all those tests to an "Excluded" directory and use
`<testsuite name="Feature"><directory>tests/Feature</directory><exclude>./tests/Feature/Excluded</exclude></testsuite>`

Comment: @ChrisRockwell Hey, thanks for the comment. I am not sure [exclude](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.3/configuration.html#the-exclude-element) works this way. Accorind to [source](https://docs.phpunit.de/en/10.3/configuration.html#the-source-element) element docs `exclude` excludes files from code coverage report, not from testing. I do not do PHP these days so cannot confirm it practically.

Answer (score 4):

Whit this PHPUnit configuration-file I have made very good experiences.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    colors="true"
    processIsolation="true"
    stopOnFailure="true"
    syntaxCheck="false"
    backupGlobals="false"
    bootstrap="test-bootstrap.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="php-dba-cache">
          <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html"
             target="build/coverage"
             charset="UTF-8"
             yui="true"
             highlight="true"
             lowUpperBound="35"
             highLowerBound="70"/>
   </logging>
    <filter>
        <whitelist addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
            <exclude>
             <file>test-bootstrap.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

https://github.com/gjerokrsteski/php-dba-cache

Comment: Where in this config are you excluding dirs/files? The <filter> tags are for code coverage.

Answer (score 4):

The [phpunit documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.testsuites) is a bit minimalistic when it comes to exclusion in a testsuite. Apparently, only **entire directories** can be excluded but not **individual files**. I would be very happy to be proven wrong. The workaround seems to be using the @group feature as [posted above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2761345/642750) by Alister Bulman.

It's kind of a pain needing to tag every single test in those test suites I'd like to keep.

Answer (score 4):

For Phpunit 6.5, `exclude` is under `whitelist`

```
<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory>src/Migrations</directory>
            <file>src/kernel.php</file>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this with a test class that I wanted to extended for other tests.  PHPUnit would issue warnings about the test file containing no tests.  Simply declaring the class inside the file `abstract` caused PHPunit to quiet down about that.

```
abstract class SetupSomeCommonThingsTestCase {
    protected function setUp(): void {
        parent:setUp();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Hey there, Make sure that you put your exclusions in the Whitelist. Example:

```
<phpunit>
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <directory suffix=".php">/not/even/looked/at/</directory>
        </blacklist>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">/path/to/test/dir/</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file suffix=".php">/path/to/fileToExclude.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.blacklist-whitelist