# How can I ignore a test method in phpunit without modifying its content?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, nunit, phpunit

What is the attribute that should be placed next to the PHP test method in order to ignore the test using PHPUnit ?

I know that for NUnit the attribute is :

```
[Test]
[Ignore]
public void IgnoredTest()
```

Answer (score 43):

You can tag the test with a [group annotation](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.group) and exclude those tests from a run.

```
/**
 * @group ignore
 */
public void ignoredTest() {
    ...
}
```

Then you can run the all the tests but ignored tests like this:

```
phpunit --exclude-group ignore
```

Comment: Note that with the default PHPUnit settings, a method that's doesn't start with `test`, e.g. `testFoo()`, won't be executed.

Comment: Note also that `public void ignoredTest()` is a syntax error in all versions of PHP; the correct syntax is (PHP 7+) `public function ignoredTest(): void` or (PHP <7) `public function ignoredTest()`.

Answer (score 23):

The easiest way would be to just change the name of the test method and avoid names starting with "test". That way, unless you tell PHPUnit to execute it using `@test`, it won't execute that test.

Also, you could tell PHPUnit [to skip a specific test](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#incomplete-and-skipped-tests.skipping-tests):

```
<?php
class ClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{     
    public function testThatWontBeExecuted()
    {
        $this->markTestSkipped( 'PHPUnit will skip this test method' );
    }
    public function testThatWillBeExecuted()
    {
        // Test something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use the method `markTestIncomplete()` to ignore a test in PHPUnit:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';

class SampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        // Optional: Test anything here, if you want.
        $this->assertTrue(TRUE, 'This should already work.');

        // Stop here and mark this test as incomplete.
        $this->markTestIncomplete(
            'This test has not been implemented yet.'
        );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't want to modify the content of the test. It is just that sometimes I want to ignore some tests, then re-add them in the testing flow.

Answer (score 5):

If you name your method not with `test` at the beginning then the method will not be executed by PHPUnit (see [here](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html)).

```php
public function willBeIgnored() {
    ...
}

public function testWillBeExecuted() {
    ...
}
```

If you want a method to be executed which does not start with `test` you can add the annotation `@test` to execute it anyway.

```php
/**
 * @test
 */
public function willBeExecuted() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you suggested in one of your comments that you do not want to change the content of a test, if you are willing to add or adjust annotations, you could abuse the `@requires` annotation to ignore tests:

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @requires PHP 9000
     */
    public function testThatShouldBeSkipped()
    {
        $this->assertFalse(true);
    }
}
```

**Note** This will only work until PHP 9000 is released, and the output from running the tests will be a bit misleading, too:

```
There was 1 skipped test:

1) FooTest::testThatShouldBeSkipped
PHP >= 9000 is required.
```

For reference, see:

- https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#incomplete-and-skipped-tests.skipping-tests-using-requires

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @Brady Olsen's answer..., you can use the [`@group` annotation](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.group) on your test method or class to put them into an arbitrary group, in this example, `ignore`:

```php
/**
 * @group ignore
 */
public function testMethod(): void {
    // ignored...
}
```

And/or:

```php
/**
 * Every test in this class will be ignored, whether it has a @group or not.
 * @group ignore
 */
class FooTest() {
    public function testBar() {
        // ignored...
    }
}
```

From there there's a couple of ways of excluding the test from being run.

### Option 0: Exclude via settings

Exclude the group automatically by changing `phpunit.xml` to include a `<groups>` structure immediately under the root `<phpunit>` node:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <!-- ... -->
    </testsuites>
    <groups>
        <exclude>
            <group>ignore</group>
        </exclude>
    </groups>
    <coverage>
        <!-- ... -->
    </coverage>
</phpunit>
```

Again, the `ignore` text is the arbitrary part, but it *must* match the `@group` annotation. AFAIK, you can add multiple `<group>` elements inside the `<exclude>`.

Also note that `<groups>` must be immediately under the `<phpunit>` node, or PHPUnit will [scream and die](https://www.catb.org/jargon/html/S/scream-and-die.html) if your `phpunit.xml` is malformed.

Older versions of PHPUnit use a `<filter>` tag with different syntax. See [this answer for PHPUnit 6.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54826607/237955). For posterity, this XML config works with PHPUnit 9.5.20.

### Option 1: Exclude via command-line flags

Exclude the group manually at run time when running phpunit:

```bash
phpunit --exclude-group ignore
```