# PHPUnit TestSuite Exclude

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

so I would like to exclude a directoy from my Testsuite just like this:

```
<testsuite name="PHPUnitWillKillMe">   
    <directory>src/*/Bundle/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
    <exclude>src/*/Bundle/*/*Bundle/Tests/Controller/</exclude>
</testsuite>
```

Everything except for the Controllers should be tested.

The thing is, it does not work. PHPUnit still runs all the tests in src/*/Bundle/*/*Bundle/Tests/Controller/ when I run

```
 phpunit --testsuite PHPUnitWillKillMe
```

Any idea?

Best Regards!

PHPUnit Version I tested this were 3.7.21 and 3.7.28.

Comment: How about this previous "solution" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736343/how-to-exclude-file-from-phpunit-test-suite-in-xml-config ?

Comment: I don't think so, see http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html -> Test Suites

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I tested it on my Symfony demo project (the `Bundles` suggests that this is what you are using) and I have the same issue. It seems to be a combination of two problems. First, there is a known bug with running PHPUnit (PHPUnit 3.7.19) with the `-c` or `--config` option:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/928

> When running it elsewhere and specifying the config file using --config, the exclude would however stop working.

Second, the `exclude` directive seems to ignore / fail when there is any globbing (`*`) in the path, so by removing the globbing, it worked for me:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        <exclude>../src/Blah/MyBundle/Tests/Controller/</exclude>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

It's the **only** way I found to exclude the Tests in `MyBundle` as required. The globbing did **not** work for the `exclude`. But then, it means you have to add as many `exclude` directives as there are folders you want to ignore.

Probable related gihub issue:
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/573

> [...] this fix lands in the 4.0 release as it breaks backwards compatibility.

- Solution #1: remove any globbing in your paths
- Solution #2: Upgrade to PHPUnit v4.* (not tested by myself, see comments, doesn't solve the problem of `exclude` paths with globbing)

Comment: I don't see how. I can even try the following and it will still run all tests in the directory <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <exclude>../src/*/Bundle/*/*Bundle/Tests</exclude> Are you experiencing the same issue? For PHPUnit Version see the updated question

Comment: I just tested and I have the *exact* same issue. See answer for more details

Comment: Thank you very much. I already found this issue on github, but maybe I am stupid or my english is bad, but what's the solution now? I have no clue... or maybe the solution is to update to 4.0.*?

Comment: I updated my answer some more, the only solution I found was to remove all globbing form the `exclude` directive... It's not a very efficient solution if you can't upgrade to version 4.0.* but I don't see any better solution for now.

Comment: I removed the accepted answer tag as this is still not working with version 4.0.12 for me

Comment: Well, I've searched some more and I couldn't find anything on exclude and globbing. So the last idea I have would be to patch the PHPUnit files if you really want/need globbing.

Answer (score 8):

Just had similar issue, phpunit has quite nice support for groups:

```
...
--filter <pattern>       Filter which tests to run.
--group ...              Only runs tests from the specified group(s).
--exclude-group ...      Exclude tests from the specified group(s).
--list-groups            List available test groups.
...
```

What you do is

```
/**
 * @group nonRunnableGroupName
 */
public function testSomething()
{ /* test here */ }
```

And run test like

```
$ phpunit -c /src --exclude-group nonRunnableGroupName
```

Comment: Edit every class that I need to exclude and add the @group annotation to every test method in every such class? Silliness.

Comment: It's only a feature, up to you how you use it.