# how to include/exclude certain groups from test-suite via phpunit.xml

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I would like to exclude or include certain test from test-suites. I would like to have some control of this via annotations/groups rather than naming specific files or folders in `phpunit.xml`

I have attempted something like this, but its appears to be ignoring the `<groups>` and/or `<include>`

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Unit">
        <directory>Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="IntegrationFirstRound">
        <directory>Integration/</directory>
        <include><!-- I want to ONLY include this group -->
            <group>first-round</group>          
        </include>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="IntegrationOther">
        <directory>Integration/</directory>
        <exclude><!-- I want to EXCLUDE this group, run all others -->
            <group>first-round</group>
        </exclude>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I don't want to move tests to different folders just to accommodate this, and I do not want to invoke phpunit multiple times from the CLI, I am hoping I can achieve the desired results via the xml config.

Comment: I just do it via the command line, but I always give my tests a group that is the name of the class, and a group that is the name of the method.  This way if I want to focus on a class I can run that group, and if I want to focus on a method I can run that group.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I was thinking about this, it would work, but with a slight complication due to another reason.

Comment: @SamAnthony, Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 10):

Ok, looking at the DOCs which should be the first place you look

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html

You need a `groups` element with the `group` inside of it.  So where you have

```
<exclude><!-- I want to EXCLUDE this group, run all others -->
     <group>first-round</group>
</exclude>
```

You should have

```
<groups>
    <exclude><!-- I want to EXCLUDE this group, run all others -->
        <group>first-round</group>
   </exclude>
</groups>
```

It doesn't really say if it should go inside the `<testsuite>`, and I never used it but I am sure if you look in the documentation you should find some examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried what you had suggested (typing mistake in my question). I have looked in the docs and experimented also. Perhaps this is not supported. Putting `<groups><exclude><group>...` just inside the `<phpunit>` tag does work, perhaps they do not belong inside the `<testsuite>` tag, the docs were not specific.

Comment: Yea, that was why I mentioned it. But, in theory you could have groups that bridge or are part of 2 testsuites so it does make some sense to do it that way.

Comment: Using `<groups>` inside `<testsuite>` is not supported. I just gave it a try but it didn't work. It will show this error:  `Element 'groups': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( directory, file, exclude ).`

Answer (score 6):

In my case I grouped as `data`

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit\Artefact;

use Tests\TestCase;

/**
 * @group data
 */
class DataMovieTest extends TestCase
{

}
```

and then run phpunit from terminal like

```sh
phpunit --exclude data
```

Comment: For excluding multiple groups use commas eg: `data,anothergroup,anotherone`

Answer (score 2):

There's a discussion in [an issue with groups in phpunit repo](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/322) where Sebastian Bergmann explicitly provides an example phpunit.xml file.

**Please find below an excerpt with example of how to place the group and include (exclude) elements**:

```
<phpunit>
 <testsuite name="My Test Suite">
  <file>Test.php</file>
 </testsuite>

 <groups>
  <include>
   <group>one</group>
  </include>
 </groups>
</phpunit>
```

[image: Screenshot of issue with groups in the phpunit repo]